# Writing files to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have developed a web application with a Node.js backend on a local machine using Webstorm IDE. Among other things, the application creates a new unique folder and writes 7 javascript (.js) files to this folder during runtime each time a user requests a new account. Everything works properly in the local development environment.

When the application is uploaded and deployed to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, and a new user is requested though the application web page, I am receiving the following 404 (Not Found) error in the browser's Developer, JavaScript Console.  The same error appears for each of the 7 files. The number 1541877962401 is the unique folder name generated by the application when a user requests a new account and user.js is one of the 7 javascript files copied to this newly created folder. savedUser is an existing folder in the file structure and is not created during runtime.

GET http://sowtest082-env.stsvxa672t.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/savedUser/1541877962401/user.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I am guessing that the application does not have the correct permissions to create the folder and/or files in AWS?

Within the context of the Elastic Beanstalk environment, what is the best method to create a folder and copy javascript files to this folder during runtime?  It is fairly easy to restructure the location of the folder and the files within it in the development environment so as to match the ASW EB environment.  Reengineering the application to store the contents of these files in an AWS MySQL database engine would take a lot more work.

Bye the way, these 7 files are not tmp files and they are not config files...

Thanks...

Comment: It's unusual that you would distribute account-specific JavaScript files around your web server in response to an account being created. Why do you need to do this, rather than drive behavior through account configuration?

Comment: Not sure why you would say it's unusual?  What exactly is unusual about it?

Comment: If I understand correctly (and I may not), you seem to be storing state on the Elastic Beanstalk instances which is not ideal. Compute instances are fungible. The fact that that state is a collection of JavaScript source files is not something you see very often. Do you genuinely have a multi-tenanted system that dynamically generates JS code that's specific to each customer?

Comment: Yes, definitely agree.  There needs to be a separation of the business logic (data) and application logic.  Question was (and is) how to do this within an AWS EB environment.  Cheers...

Comment: It might help if we understood why you are dynamically writing JavaScript files whenever an account is created. What is in these JS files?

Comment: Not sure where you are going with this?  These are data files plain and simple.  I fail to see how the content makes any difference?  Do you have anything resembling a solution to this problem?  If not, I really need to move on.  Cheers...

Comment: At this point all I can suggest is that you review how you intend to persist state, by reading https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.concepts.design.html#concepts.concepts.design.storage

Comment: Thank you for your input. Cheers...